# How to use System.console as Apache Flink source

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Apache Flink provides a lot of different streaming sources but I was wondering whether it's possible to use the Console as a source of data. I haven't found any examples online.

I've come up with this:

```
DataStream<String> consoleInput = flinkEnv.addSource(new SourceFunction<String>() {

            @Override
            public void run(SourceContext<String> ctx) throws Exception {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (true)
                    ctx.collect(sc.nextLine());
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel() {
            }
        });
```

I was wondering if this is ok or is there a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Using the console as a data source is certainly doable, but has the issue that your application won't be fault tolerant, since Flink won't be able rewind and replay the input stream in the event of a failure.

But this often done for prototypes and experiments, typically with a `SocketTextStreamFunction`, as in

```
env.addSource(new SocketTextStreamFunction("localhost", 9999, "\n", -1))
```

You can then use netcat to attach the console to port 9999

```
nc -lk 9999
```

or, as some versions of netcat require,

```
nc -l -p 9000
```

Comment: Yes I saw this in the tutorials. I wanted to use the console for experimenting :)